# Jquery tools not working in Webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, jquery-tools

I am using jQuery Tools and specifically the function .tabs (http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/index.html)

The function works fine if I use

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
```

But I also need to use the function in a `<select>` element.
This is working fine for Firefox, Internet Explorer etc. but not on webkit based web browsers. (Chrome, Safari...)

Why? Here's a working example of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/holmzor666/QXkbx/

Answer (score 0):

see this [edit](http://jsfiddle.net/QXkbx/4/)

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});​
```

Comment: But I also need to use the function in a <select> element. This is working fine for Firefox, internet explorer etc But not on webkit based webbrowsers. (Chrome, Safari...)